# How to use the function from the js file returned by an API in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, es6-modules

I've been using **create-react-app**

This is the sample request in the **`componentDidMount()`**:

```
axios.get("/")
  .then(res => {
    const test = res.data;
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I want to use the response of the `API` which is a `javascript` code.

Here's the sample return of the **`API`**:

```
const sample = props => (React.createElement('div'))
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to use the **sample** function and pass data to it and make it display in the current component

```
render() {
  return test.sample(SomeData)
}
```

Comment: Please be clear on what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Already did. @KannanT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems very wrong to do that, but you can use eval on the response:

```
eval(res.data);
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!) is a write-up on why you should never use `eval`.

Comment: But I can't pass data to it

Comment: What do you mean you can't pass data to it?

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is using the component passed by the API to the current component. For example: 
const test = eval(res.data);

render() {
  test.sample(dataToPass);
}

Comment: You want the API to send, for example, <div>{"Hello " + name}</div>. And make the react render it? (I'm a bit confused)

Comment: The API will send a js code and then I will use that code  and pass data to it and render it

Comment: @user8956707 first you need to return from the axios request